# choose unique image ids randomly from a list of image ids - python

Tags: python, numpy, random, machine-learning

I am trying to train a neural network in keras which requires me to train the model in batches. I want to use a batch size of 3 images and there are a total of 20 images.

I want to randomly choose 3 unique image IDs from a list of 20 image IDs in one batch. This process will be re-iterated for the entire epoch.

```
import numpy as np
image_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
epoch = 10
num = 3 # number of values to choose from

for ep in range(epoch):
    count = 0
    ilist = image_list

    while count <= len(image_list):

        if len(ilist)<num:
            # This condition works when sample size is greater than population size
            image_index = list(np.random.choice(image_list,len(image_list)))
        else:
            image_index = list(np.random.choice(image_list,num,replace = False))

        for c in image_index:
            ilist.remove(c)
        # image_index
        # data loading code
        # feature extraction code
        # model training
        count += len(image_index)
```

image_list is the list of 20 unique image IDs. In every epoch, train_id will randomly choose 3 unique IDs as long as some_condition is True. I get an error in train_id **('Sample size is greater than Population Size')** when I randomly choose 3 values when there are only 2 unique values left in image_list.

I tried to find any replacement of np.random.choice for this error but couldn't find any.

Comment: Did you mean `replace=False` instead of `return=False` there? (Also, I assume `9,,10` is supposed to be `9,10`—I'd just fix that myself, but I'm not sure about fixing the other error, so I'm leaving it up to you to turn your code into a [mcve].)

Comment: Anyway, are you actually removing these values from `image_list` somewhere? If so, then yes, when you get down to 2 elements, of course you can't select 3. In fact, think about what you're asking: "How do I choose 10*3 unique elements without replacement from 20 elements?" The only answer is: you can't, because there aren't that many elements to choose. If that isn't what you actually wanted to do, explain what you wanted to do. And show the code that causes the error, because the code you've given shows the two errors I mentioned in my first comment, and no errors at all once you fix those.

Comment: I have made some edits in the code. I understand that I can't choose 3 values when only 2  numbers are left. I just couldn't figure out the condition that I should use to circumvent the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an idea. it makes sense if your data is not big.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[100],[200],[300],[400]])

np.random.shuffle(x)

for i in range(0,3):
    do_something = x[i]
    print(do_something)
```

or something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[100],[200],[300],[400]])

for i in range(10):#epoch:
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    do_something = x[:3,:]
    print(do_something)
```